# How do i use jQuery to fade a picture out then go to a new page?

Tags: jquery, html, image, fade

The opening page of my website is picture and when clicked i want it to fade out then go to the main page. Should i fade out the picture then fade in the body of the next page or is there a way to do it all in one?

```
<script>
 $(document).click(function(){     
    $('#beach').fadeTo(3000,0.30, function() {
       $("#beach").attr("src",$("#link").attr("href"));
    }).fadeTo(500,1);
    return false;

 });
</script> 

<a href="welcomepage.html#link"><img id="beach" src="wedfronttest.jpg"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `$('body').load($(this).attr('href'));` will load the links content into the body of the page that you're on, if that's what you're after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Froxz idea, I assume the best option is

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).prop('href');
    $('#beach').fadeOut(function() { 
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhx8n/2) to see it in action!
(Remember you won't get redirected at JSFiddle, but you will see the idea)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefaults();
var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#beach').fadeOut(function() { 
              window.location = url;
        });
    });
```